# "Updating PHPUnit Version..." window appear before unit tests start

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit, composer-php, phpstorm

Each time I run unit tests in PhpStorm 2016.2.1, a window (such as the one shown below) appears for 30-40 seconds. Is it possible to remove it completely?

[image: PhpStorm window]

I tried running PHPUnit 5.6 and 5.7 as phar file formats and through composer autoloader, but the same thing happens

Comment: TBH -- no idea -- never seen such dialog/popup. How do you run it -- is it local one opr via SSH/HTTP? In any case --  you may try PhpStorm 2016.3 EAP build -- at least to check if it's any different there -- https://blog.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/2016/10/phpstorm-2016-3-eap-163-6110/

Comment: same effect on EAP

Comment: One idea though -- I thunk this must be "new" functionality (2016.2 I believe) where IDE tries to determine PHPUnit version so that it will be executing the tests in most optimal way (with newer versions -- via PHPUnit runner directly, with older -- via intermediate helper script). 30-40 seconds --  that could be a xdebug delay (or something like that) where PHP is possibly running in debug mode (I mean -- xdebug thinks that you want to debug this script) and since it sees no response it terminates such execution and you can proceed as usual.

Comment: So .. try either disabling any xdebug extensions to start with; and if you need it (e.g. for code coverage data) -- try then collect xdebug logs and see what it has to say

Comment: i totally disable xdebug in php.ini and window start to disappear much faster, but still i see it approximately 10 sec

Comment: No other ideas unfortunately. Consider contacting Support team -- https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/requests/new (do not forget to provide them your idea.log file (Help | Show Log in...) and other relevant info -- they will decide if this is a local issue (your specific (system?) config) or something can be done from their side. P.S. Try different PHP version/build and unload as many modules as possible -- maybe one of them does it...

Comment: BTW: Similar issue https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-33549 was marked as duplicate of https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-32845 -- consider watching the latest (star/vote/comment) to get notified on any progress.

Comment: Are you running PHPUnit on a remote host or docker?

Comment: no. i run it locally. BTW the problem is gone yesterday because of moon phase changes. PhpStorm don't show this window at all, and i really have no idea why it happens.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The root of the problem was my SSD drive. I create and delete files very frequently so in my case i need to send TRIM command to it. This could be done through Windows disk optimization.

Comment: Doesn't make sense at all. What are you trying to say? What TRIM command?

Answer (score 0):

Reproduced with docker/Symfony 5/Simple PHPUnit. I fixed this with absolute path to simple phpunit like this.

[image]